# Suppose that if G is a group, H is a subgroup of G, and K is a subgroup of H.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Suppose that if G is a group, H is a subgroup of G, and K is a subgroup of H.
Show that if K is a normal subgroup of G, then K is a normal subgroup of H.

Ive tried writing out what is implied from all of the givens, but i guess I'm just having trouble seeing a connection.
K is a normal subgroup of G tells us that
aK=Ka for all a in G
therefore aKa^(-1)=K for all a in G
We want to show that aKa^(-1)=K for all a in G
I also have all of the implications of subgroups from my class, but i can't find one that appears to work.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

He who can do the more can do the less.

Comment: I love your hint! It's like in some fairy tales, where the main character travel far to meet some wise sorcerer to ask him for a hint and this sorecerer may give him the advice like yours! (I'm not joking, the problem is such that it is really hard to give any hint not giving the whole solution so your hint is just perfect) +1

Comment: Some down-voter doesn't like my hint?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: Taking $K$ as the kernel of some homomorphism $H \to P$ (which one?) for some group $P$  is another way to do this.

I think it's a little cleaner than the bare-handed way.